# Bibliographic style for manually added bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, formatting

I am using the `thebibliography` environment inside a LaTeX document. Right now, the entries appear in PDF like:

> [1] DACUNHA-CASTELLE, D., et DUFLO, M., Probabilites et statistique-problemes a
>   temps mobile, Masson paris Milan Barcelone, 1993.
>
> [2] DOEBLIN, W., Sur les sommes d ‘ un grand nombres des variables
>   aleatoires independantes, Bull. Soc. Math. France, 53(1939), 23-32,
>   35-64.

I would like to appear the numbered items followed by a dot, with no paranthesis, smth as:

> 1. DACUNHA-CASTELLE, ...
> 2. DOEBLIN, W., Sur les sommes...

I suppose I should specify a style inside the `\bibliographystyle` command, but which one?

Thanks.

Comment: Styles work only with automatically created bbl-files. Try `\makeatletter\def\@biblabel#1{#1.}\makeatother`.

Comment: Thanks Ulrike, this solved my problem: I added the command you mentioned just before opening the thebibliography environment.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following hack to override thebibliography numbering style:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{#1.}
\makeatother
```

This will override the definition of @biblabel, which is an internal macro that provides the listing labels of bibitems.